# Can I use multiple search criteria in one python regex query to return a tuple?

Tags: python, regex, tuples

I have a log file that appends new logs as the program runs on different days. Each iteration there will be a new Product Version and Launch Switch. I need the `Product Version: [0-9-]*`and `Launch Switch: \w*` from each iteration as a tuple.

Currently I am doing this:

```
ver = re.findall(r'(?<=Product Version: )[0-9.]*', s)

launch = re.findall(r'(?<=Launch Switch: )\w*', s)
```

Then later I'm iterating through `ver` and `launch` to create the tuples. It works, but it's not pretty and I'm sure there's a more Pythonic way of doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple capturing groups within your regex pattern; `re.findall` will then return them as a tuple. For example:

```
>>> data = "Product Version: 0.0.1 | Launch Switch: hello | Product Version: 2.3.4 | Launch Switch: world"
>>> re.findall("Product Version: ([0-9.]+).*?Launch Switch: (\w+)", data)
[('0.0.1', 'hello'), ('2.3.4', 'world')]
```

From [the `re.findall` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; **this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group**. Empty matches are included in the result unless they touch the beginning of another match.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `zip`:

```
ver_launch_tuples = zip(re.findall(r'(?<=Product Version: )[0-9.]*', s),
                        re.findall(r'(?<=Launch Switch: )\w*', s))
```

This will create a list of (ver,launch) tuples.

Comment: what a beautiful function! i am loving python more and more every day. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how "pythonic" this is, but it will get you your tuple from a string that has these items in either order:

```
import re
str = """Product Version: 23423
Launch Switch: foiwjefj"""
tuple([word for sublist in [[x for x in f if x != ''] for f in re.findall(
    r'Product Version: (\d+)|Launch Switch: (\w+)', str)] for word in sublist])
```

This of course makes some assumptions:

1. `Product Version` and `Launch Swtich` always come in that order
2. Are not empty
3. There is only one of them per string.